# Can i have multiple workspaces in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I want to have multiple workspaces in the same VScode window, one for work and one for personal projects. Currently I have two workspaces saved:

**work.code-workspace,
personal.code-workspace**

Whenever i click one of the above workspaces, it'll open a new VScode window. I want to have both the workspaces in one window so i can switch between them easily.

The reason I don't want to have my personal project directory/folder in the same workspace as my work is because it uses a different virtual environment and different versions of frameworks. For eg: in my personal projects file I have `from flask import Flask`, if I have this file in the same workspace as my work then it'll give me the `import flask could not be resolved from source pylance` error. But when I try it in a different workspace, the import works fine even though I use flask at work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [vscode-workspace-switcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sadesyllas.vscode-workspace-switcher) extension adds commands for opening a workspace in the current window or a new window, along with corresponding keybindings.

Answer (score 0):

See at this conversation, I understand that is impossible to have two workspaces in the same VSC's window.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43188

I hope this could help you.

Answer (score -1):

I frequently use different workspaces for different code-bases (projects) at work. File/Open Recent/... generally gives you a list of recently opened workspaces.

Comment: I also open separate workspaces concurrently but right-clicking on the VS Code icon on my Windows taskbar and selecting the appropriate workspace.